# Grails - how to return a variable from controller's action to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm trying to return a result from controller's action method to JavaScript function.

I tried two ways of solving this:

first:

Method in a controller:

```
def addUser(String name, String id1, String id2) {
    return "myValue"
}
```

JavaScript function:

```
function myFunction(userId1, userId2, username) {
  var id1 = $(userId1).val();
  var id2 = $(userId2).val();
  var name = $(username).val();
 // <g:remoteFunction action="addUser" params="{name:name,id1:id1,id2:id2}" />
  var variable = ${remoteFunction(action:'addUser', params:[name:name,id1:id1,id2:id2])};
  alert(variable)
}
```

It only displayed "object Object"

second:

Method in a controller:

```
def addUser(String name, String id1, String id2) {
    return [value:"myValue"]
}
```

JavaScript function:

```
function myFunction(userId1, userId2, username) {
  var id1 = $(userId1).val();
  var id2 = $(userId2).val();
  var name = $(username).val();
 // <g:remoteFunction action="addUser" params="{name:name,id1:id1,id2:id2}" />
  ${remoteFunction(action:'addUser', params:[name:name,id1:id1,id2:id2])};
      var variable = "${value}";
  alert(variable)
}
```

Doesn't display anything.

I also tried putting my variable into the session which only worked after refreshing the page.
I ran out of ideas. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the **remoteFunction** asynchronously, which is the default, but you aren't providing any callback.  So what you need to do is pass in the **update** method with an id of some area of the page that you want to have changed.  Here is a great tutorial on using the remoteFunction method: http://javadeveloper.asia/grails-ajax-tutorial-remotefunction-tag/.  Also, here is the grails documentation on that method: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html.

Something like this:

```
<div id="myarea"></div>
<g:remoteFunction action="addUser" params="[name:name,id1:id1,id2:id2]" update="myarea" />
```

You can then render a template from the controller that has your variable:

```
def addUser(String name, String id1, String id2) {
  render(template: 'myvar', model: [myvar: "value"])
}
```

In the template (_myvar.gsp):

```
<g:set name="myvar" value="${myvar}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks adavis. I managed to get the result into JavaScript from the controller. Unfortunately my solution is not suited for anything else than a demo/prototype page.

JavaScript function:

```
function myFunction(userId1, userId2, username) {
  var id1 = $(userId1).val();
  var id2 = $(userId2).val();
  var name = $(username).val();
  var tabNr = getTabNumber();

  <g:remoteFunction action="addChat" params="{tabNumber:tabNr,id1:id1,id2:id2}" update="addChatResult"/>

  setTimeout(function(){
     var x = document.getElementById("addChatResult");
     if (x.innerHTML.trim() != ""){
         if (x.innerHTML.trim() == "noRoomsAvailable"){
             alert("Maximum number of private conversations is 10.");
         }
         else if (x.innerHTML.trim() == "success") {
            my_function(name, id1, id2);
         }
         else {
             alert("Failed to start a private chat")
         }
         x.innerHTML = "";
     }
  }, 500);
}
```

Div to store the result:

```
<div id="addChatResult" style="display: none;"></div>
```

addChat.gsp:

```
<g:set var="tomorrow" value="${new Date() + 1}" />
${status}
```

Method in the controller:

```
def addChat(int tabNumber, int id1, int id2) {

  String result = ""
    if (chatRooms.hasRoomsLeft()) {
      chatRooms.populateRoom(tabNumber, id1, id2)
      result = "success"
    }
    /* ... */
    else {
      result = "fail"
    }
    [status:result]
}
```

So what it does is:
 1. myFunction() triggers an action in a controller.
 2. div addChatResult gets updated
 3. myFunction() reads the data from addChatResult, and behaves accordingly

There are many problems with this approach. First: myFunction() waits for addChatResult to be refreshed (setTimeout) and there's no way of knowing if it's done already. Second: using div addChatResult allows me only to return single Strings and no lists of objects.
I would like to find a way to skip point 2. and return the result directly to JavaScript method without using any temp divs.
Please advise.